# Why does the animation not run smoothly in ipad mini?

Tags: ios, animation, ipad-mini

This is my animation code:

```
CGRect newRect = [self paraStyle:STYLE_DOWNUP currRect:myView.frame];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    myView.frame = newRect;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    ......
}];
```

It is  common animation code for implementing `UIView` animation. This code runs very well on iPhone 4 and iPad 2. But on the iPad mini, it is not smooth. There was a little shakiness.

Does anyone have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my false. The reason is that:

```
1. The ipad mini is not very power in image process.
2. The background image of the animation view is translucent. So it cost very murch!
```